# HTMLParser for Python 3.4

Tags: python, html-parser

I have some code written in Python (2.7) which uses HTMLParser.
I am using Python 3.4 currently.

I can not find the HTMLParser download module.

If it exists, can anyone share the link?
If not, what should I do?

Comment: Have you tried the inbuilt `2to3` python converter? Also check https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

Comment: I can find the docs but not the download module. i can only find download module for python 2.7. Here it is:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/HTMLParser

Answer (score 14):

You don't need install html parser for Python 3. It's pre installed. Just use:

```
import html.parser
```